# RANDOM.ORG сделать public ссылку

Tags: случайные-числа

Сделал некий запрос на random org api , но по итогу получил лишь такой ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то я не наблюдаю там поле `hashedApiKey` чтобы потом сделать ссылку. Как в данном случае:

```
{
"method":"generateSignedIntegers",
"hashedApiKey":"oT3AdLMVZKajz0pgW/8Z+t5sGZkqQSOnAi1aB8Li0tXgWf8LolrgdQ1wn9sKx1ehxhUZmhwUIpAtM8QeRbn51Q==",
"n":6,"min":1,
"max":6,
"replacement":true,
"base":10,
"data":[6,1,4,4,3,6],
"completionTime":"2014-06-03 17:15:13Z",
"serialNumber":79924
}
```

Это пример JSON массива который должен быть для проверки, но у меня получается почему-то не такой результат (см скрин первый).

Почему мне не возвращают `hashedApiKey`

В мануале : https://api.random.org/verify/manual

Почему-то написанно:

> Вы можете использовать наш API для проверки подписи, но это также возможно сделать сами. На этой странице объясняется, как выполнить проверку подписи без использования RANDOM.ORG API.

Но я не нашёл как сделать это с использованием API, вместо этого там приводится пример с работой на LINUX.

Как это можно организовать?

Хочется сделать публичную ссылку на которую может перейти любой человек.

Answer (score 1):

Опять, всегда так. Ищешь проблему час.. два.. Задаёшь уже вопрос на форуме, а в итоге сразу находишь ответ на свой вопрос.

В методе при запросе на RANDOM ORG API нужно указать `"method": "generateSignedIntegers"` а не `"method": "generateIntegers"`

Тогда все данные прийдут для запроса на верификацию и создание паблик ссылки.

Всем спасибо :^ , чтобы я без вас делал!

Comment: `чтобы я без вас делал` старался бы чуть внимательнее разобраться в проблеме и самостоятельно найти решение? :) Это в итоге и вышло. Поверьте, так лучше.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin , просто ответ пришёл тогда, когда я задал вопрос именно сюда..

Comment: Почитайте про [утёнка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%83%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0). У вас как раз такая ситуация. Но не всегда стоит в качестве утёнка использовать сообщества вроде ruSO :)